# Method validation or better approaches for showing that there is a $g\in G\backslash H$ such that $g^{−1}Hg=H$. For $|G|=p^n$ (prime $p$)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $p$ be a prime number, and $G$ be a finite group of order $p^n$
>   with $n\ge 1$. If $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$, show that there is
>   a $g\in G\backslash H$ such that $g^{−1}Hg=H$.

I thought to do induction on $n$. I think for the base case we can take $n=1$ if we try to prove that "there is no $H$ for which all $g\in G\backslash H$ do not satisfy $g^{−1}Hg=H$".

Then assume true for $n=k$ then by Lagrange's theorem for a group $G$ of order $p^{k+1}$ any subgroup is either of order $p^k$ or $p^m$ for $m<k$.

In the first case let the subgroup of order $p^k$ be $H$. Then $G/H\cong C_p$ and the result follows.

In the second case **any subgroup of order $p^m$ for $m<k$ of $G$ is a subgroup of some subgroup $H$ of order $p^k$ of $G$** and then the result follows by induction.

--

Firstly I am not convinced that the bit in bold is true, if it is how might I prove it?

Secondly is there anything wrong anywhere else? Is the method even valid?

Lastly, is there a better way to do it? I don't think the question intended induction, is there a more elegant way that avoids induction and uses only groups results?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: As to your last point, the "usual" way of doing this is to consider the action of $G$ on the cosets of $H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Sylow's First Theorem which states for each group $G$, s.t. $|G| = p^nm$, where $p \not| m$ we have that for each $i<n$ every subroup of $H \le G$ of order $p^i$ is normal group in a subgroup of order $p^{i+1}$.

In fact using group action of left translation (multuplying H by elements of g from the left) on the left cosets of $H$ in $G$ you can prove that $[N[H]:H] \equiv [G:H] \pmod p$ for a $p-$subgroup of any group $G$. As $p \mid [G:H]$ we have that $p \mid [N[H]:H]$, so $H$ isn't it's own normalizer. Hence there exists $g \in N[H]$, but not in $H$ and obviously we have that $g^{-1}Hg = H$

Comment: Thanks. Does my method work at all or does the question demand a better approach (like yours)?

Comment: @Aka_aka_aka_ak I think your method works definitely. In the first case I think you might add why $H$ is normal is $G$, as we can't assume that $G/H$ exists. In the second case the bold part is the main thing and you should prove it, but I can't see another way except for using what I have already mentioned. But if you use that then you don't need induction, as I've shown.